# How can I link to the images in the carousel and make it open on another site?

Tags: flutter

How do I get the images on the merry-go-round in my Flutter application to open on another site?
clicking on an image will show how another site

````
```final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/book-7a285.appspot.com/o/anaiki.jpg?alt=media&token=18fc2b2a-1ebf-4def-980a-96d8e0126428',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/book-7a285.appspot.com/o/anabi.jpg?alt=media&token=75e14984-542b-49ce-a329-b0317ffb9276',


  ];  
class CarouselWithIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselWithIndicatorState createState() => _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
}   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: true,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.2,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    ```
````